# OCamlでFormat.fprintfを使った関数の文字列への変換

Tags: ocaml

以下のようなFormatをつかったデータを出力する関数があります:

```
type e = Int of int | Add of e * e

let rec pp_e ppf = function
  | Int(i) -> Format.fprintf ppf "Int(%d)@?" i
  | Add(e1, e2) -> Format.fprintf ppf "Add(%a,%a)@?" pp_e e1 pp_e e2
```

この関数は以下のようにすると標準出力へ出力出来ます:

```
let _ = pp_e Format.std_formatter (Add(Int 1, Int 2))
```

ここで、この関数を利用して以下のような型のeを文字列に変換する関数を作りたいのですが:

```
let show_e (e:e):string = ...
```

一般的にFormatを使った関数を使って文字列へ変換する方法を教えてください。

Comment: 一般的に、質問者が何を試してどううまくいかないのか、の説明を尽していない場合、問題の周辺について知識がある人がもし存在していても適切に答えられません。解答者側が無駄な空気を読むのはお互いの時間の無駄です。どなたかが減点されているのもそういう意味ではないでしょうか

Comment: Format.fprintfを使った関数を使った場合に、バッファを使って文字列に変換したい場合がたまにあって、ググるとすぐ見つかると嬉しいので質問して見た次第です。試した事はgoogleで検索して、結果を見つけて解決しているのですけど、自分で解決しましただと、StackOverFrowに簡単なノウハウがない状況が続くのでそういうノウハウも欲しいなと思う訳です。

Comment: 上のご質問だけだと `Buffer`、 `str_formatter`, `kfprintf`使う方法と 3つくらい解答を思いつくんですが、どれが適しているかちょっとわからないんです。(`sprintf` は試してみたが上手くいかなかったとか) もっとコンテクストを書いて頂けると答もつきやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問を編集したのですが、show_e のような関数を作る場合に気軽にささっとつかえれば、方法はどれでもよいのです。幾つかあるのであればそれぞれのメリット、デメリットもあると便利かもしれないですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

上の例を改変して答えます。Format で AST をプリントする場合、間違いなく box を使うものですし (でなければ Printf でよい)、その場合、 flush するとレイアウトが狂います。また、flush が入っていると後の説明にも支障をきたすので、外してあります。

```
open Format

type e = Int of int | Add of e * e

let rec pp_e ppf = function
  | Int(i) -> fprintf ppf "Int(%d)" i
  | Add(e1, e2) -> fprintf ppf "Add(@[%a,@ %a@])" pp_e e1 pp_e e2

let rec make = function
  | 0 -> Int 0
  | n -> Add (Int n, Add (make (n-1), make (n-1)))

let e = make 3
```

一番簡単なのは `str_formatter` に書込み、結果を `flush_str_formatter ()` で取り出す方法です。
ただしこれはグローバル状態 `stdbuf` を変更するのでマルチスレッドでは誤動作しません。
シングルスレッドでも、`stdbuf` に既にゴミが入っているとゴミが出力されます。良い方法ではありません:

```
let to_string' p x =
  p str_formatter x;
  flush_str_formatter ()

let () = prerr_endline (to_string' pp_e e)
```

自前のバッファを用意し、それに書き込むフォーマッタを定義し、そのフォーマッタに書き込むことで、
グローバル状態を使うことを避けることができます:

```
let to_string p x =
  let buf = Buffer.create 0 in
  let ppf = formatter_of_buffer buf in
  p ppf x;
  pp_print_flush ppf ();
  Buffer.contents buf

let () = prerr_endline (to_string pp_e e);;
```

ここで注意しなければいけないのは出力を取り出す前にフラッシュしなければいけない事。`pp_print_flush ppf ()` を明示的に呼び出さないかぎり Format のレイアウトエンジンはレイアウトを終了できず結果をバッファに書き込みできません。これを忘れると結果が全く出て来なかったり中途半端になる可能性があります。

`to_string` のような関数を定義する前に、フォーマット結果を文字列にする方法としてまず思い付くのは `sprintf` だと思いますが、`sprintf` と `pp_e` を組合せようとしてもうまくいきません:

```
% let s = sprintf "%a" pp_e e;;

Characters 25-29:
Error: This expression has type Format.formatter -> e -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type unit -> 'a -> string
       Type Format.formatter is not compatible with type unit
```

これは `sprintf` の第一引数の型 `('a, unit, string) format` が十分ではなくフォーマット文字列中に `%a` を取れないからです。

`%a` を使って最終結果を文字列として得るため、 `format4` というデータ型と`kfprintf` 関数が追加されました。この `kfprintf` を使うと自前の `%a` が使える「良い」 `sprintf` を定義することができます:

```
let sprintf' fmt =
  let buf = Buffer.create 0 in
  let ppf = formatter_of_buffer buf in
  kfprintf (fun ppf -> pp_print_flush ppf (); Buffer.contents buf) ppf fmt

let () = prerr_endline (sprintf' "%a" pp_e e);;
```

以前はこの `sprintf'` を自作する必要がありました。あまりに不便なのでOCaml 4.01.0 からは `asprintf` という物が用意されています:

```
let () = prerr_endline (asprintf "%a" pp_e e);;
```

`%a` が使えない `sprintf` の方はそのままになっていますが、後方互換性のためだと思われます。

`to_string p x` を使うか `asprintf "%a" p x` を使うかですが、場合によります。`"%a"` なのであれば前者が短く効率も良い。`"result= @[%a@]"` のようにさらにレイアウトを行わせたい場合には `asprintf` を使うことになります。

Comment: なるほど。バッファ使う場合は何か問題ありそうだなともやもやしていたのですがハッキリしました。バッファを使ってちゃんとしようとすると不便なので、sprintfで%aが使えれば良いのだけど、以前動いていたプログラムが動かなくなっては困るので、asprintfがあるわけですね。